# Passing parameters to a function invoked in a separate thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parameters

Consider the following Java code on Android.  I start threads in a for loop.  Inside the thread, I am invoking a method with parameters that are changed by the for loop.  Are the parameters 'start_index' and 'end_index' passed correctly so that the for loop doesn't change the value of these parameters after the thread is invoked?

```
for (int i=0; i<chunk_counts*chunk; i+=chunk){

                        final int  start_index=i; //start_index
                        final int end_index = i + chunk; //set end_index

                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                threadCount.getAndIncrement();
                                ProcessAttendanceAuto(data, start_index, 
end_index);
                            }
                        }).start();


                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These values are effectively `final`, thus they're thread safe and you don't need to worry about them changing over time. Also, when being passed to the `Runnable` and when invoking `ProcessAttendanceAuto`, they're copied.

For example, this

```
final int startIndex = i;
final int endIndex = i + 1;
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final int test = startIndex;
        final int test2 = endIndex;
    }
}).start();
```

Is translated to

```
NEW java/lang/Thread
DUP
NEW so/Test$1
DUP
ILOAD 2
ILOAD 3
INVOKESPECIAL so/Test$1.<init> (II)V
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Thread.<init> (Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
```

Here

```
INVOKESPECIAL so/Test$1.<init> (II)V
```

you can see the generated class

```
class $1 implements Runnable
```

accepts two `int` arguments in its constructor.
This means the values `startIndex` and `endIndex` are copied.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for sharing this information. Multithreading is always a challenge.